# Algorithm for finding Min Max of Inventory

Tags: max, min, inventory-management

I've been looking over the web on and off for the past couple of weeks regarding Inventory Control Systems.

I understand that Min Max Inventory Systems have fallen out of favour as of late, but regardless that is what I am working with.

My question is about the algorithm for deciding the initial min and max values for a particular piece of inventory. The online information I have found so far only relates to what happens after you decide your min max values, but nothing on how to choose them. This could be as easy as giving me a better search term I don't know.

So far I've come up with:

Minimum Value :-
Take the Lead time it takes to receive the part. Then find the Mode of part usage during that time span Then make the minimum that number plus perhaps 10% extra to cover any spikes in requirements.

Maximum Value :-
I haven't a clue. The limits on this seem to be warehouse space and cost of the parts, plus perhaps a risk calculation on the likely hood of the part being damaged or going into obsolescence before being used.

If you can offer any help or a point in thh right direction I would be grateful this is something that I thought was going to be an easy task that has turned into a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

For this function, my company distinguishes between two types of parts: those which have to be imported and those which can be purchased from local suppliers.

For imported parts, the minimum amount should be, as you say, the average amount used per month multiplied by the lead time in months. There is no maximum: an order should be large enough that it covers the amount which you need to produce now and still leaves you with the minimum amount in inventory. There are also two more factors which should be taken into account: the minimum amount that the supplier is prepared to sell and the 'step' value: for example, a supplier might define a minimum order of 500 items with a step of 100 (so if you need 501, you will have to order 600).

For parts purchased locally, there is no minimum as they can always be replenished.

Comment: We maintain a collection of old parts in stock to allow us opportunity to service older equip. We currently wait for when we miss out on a repair job because of lack of parts and then we evaluate it and up the minimum just a bit. Our current maximums are essentially the same as our minimum unless there is a particularly long lead time for the part.  Then we go through a daily system of ordering to keep everything up. I was hoping that there was a more technical algorithm that I could have used to minimize the value of stock held on the premises while still responding to part consumption.